# Subsetting data in R to remove rows if values for two variables are NA

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I want to remove all rows from my dataset that are NA in two columns. If a row has a non-NA value in either column, I want to keep it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 4, 6, NA, 3, NA),
             b = c(5, 4, 8, NA, 6, 7))

df1 <- df %>%
  filter(is.na(a) == FALSE | is.na(b) == FALSE)
```

and you get:

```
> df1
   a b
1  2 5
2  4 4
3  6 8
4  3 6
5 NA 7
```

Comment: I'd suggest just `library(dplyr)` unless you really need the entire `tidyverse`.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a couple of `base R` suggestions.  Loop through the columns of datasets, convert it to a logical vector, and collapse the logical vectors by comparing each corresponding element with `Reduce`, negate the output and subset the dataset

```
df[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, is.na)),]
```

Or converting the logical matrix (`!is.na(df)`) to a logical `vector` to subset the dataset

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df))>0,]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 4, 6, NA, 3, NA),
         b = c(5, 4, 8, NA, 6, 7))
```